# Ardor3d API / User Documentation

Tags: ardor3d

I recently (as of monday just gone) started a new job where the system they use is based upon ardor3d.

I require a full API list / Any user documentation available as the company have none and from what I can tell the main author of the technology has decided to shut the project down

Any docs or help you gave provide would be fantastic

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read those articles:
[Ardor3D on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JMonkeyEngine#Ardor_3D_fork)

[JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation Overview](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Ardor3D_Overview)

To sum up, your link points out to an obsolete unmaintained version of Ardor3D. I'll publish a huge tutorial about JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation before the end of September with the detailed procedure to install it, build it and use it with Ant, Maven, Gradle, Eclipse, Netbeans and in command line.

JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation is alive, I can publish the Java documentation Monday or Tuesday if you really need it.

If you prefer using an obsolete version of Ardor3D, I won't be able to help you and you will miss tons of enhancements, more than 60 commits. Feel free to contact the JogAmp community on [our official forum](http://forum.jogamp.org).

N.B: The brand new **JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation user's guide** is [here](https://gouessej.wordpress.com/2014/11/22/ardor3d-est-mort-vive-jogamps-ardor3d-continuation-ardor3d-is-dead-long-life-to-jogamps-ardor3d-continuation/), it contains about 95 simple examples, good luck.

N.B: The API documentation is [here](http://jogamp.org/deployment/ardor3d/javadoc/).

Comment: That's fantastic thanks. I'm in no huge rush and knowing that the documentation is coming out soon is great.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't hesitate to contact us (or me personally) if you need some help. The Java documentation is easy to generate with Maven, it won't be a problem.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I still have to take care of it. You can still generate the documentation by yourself with Maven in the meantime.

Comment: You can generate the documentation by running "mvn install" and then "mvn site". I'm going to publish it very soon.

Comment: I'm currently uploading the API documentation right now ;)

Answer (score -1):

It would appear that for all my searching I've found something.

Given how long it took to find and how obscure it was to actually find I'm going to leave the link for it here:

http://grepcode.com/project/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ardor3d/ardor3d-core/

In the hopes that if someone else is ever in the same position this'll help them

Comment: It's obsolete, look at my answer.